# Как отредактировать код?

Tags: php, wordpress

столкнулся с проблемой, не могу отредактировать код, чтобы он работал  через php-snippet

```
<?php
$arPrices = get_field('price');

if(!empty($arPrices)){ ?>
    <div class="prices">
        <h2 class="prices-head">
        <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/departments/sterilizatsiya/sobaki/"){?>
            Цены на стерилизацию собаки в Москве
        <?php }else{?>
            Стоимость услуг
        <?php }?>
        </h2>
        <?php 
        foreach($arPrices as $price){ ?>
            <div class="price-item">
                <div class="price-item-name col-sm-10"><? if (!empty($price['service_name'])) : echo '<b>'.$price['service_name'].'</b>'; endif; if (!empty($price['description'])) echo '<br>'.$price['description']; ?></div>
                <div class="price-value col-sm-2"><? if (!empty($price['service_price'])) : ?><? if (!empty($price['from'])) : ?>от <? endif; ?><span><?  echo $price['service_price']; ?></span> ₽<? else : ?>по запросу<? endif; ?></div>
            </div>
        <? }
        ?>

         <div class="order-form hidden_form">
            <?php get_template_part('sections/form-order'); ?>  
        </div>
```

Comment: и какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: пустая страница просто

Comment: ну так включи вывод ошибок

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/c/cn76510/public_html/cms/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь IDE типа PhpStorm с нормальной подсветкой синтаксиса - сразу увидите ошибки.

У вас `if` не закрыт, не хватает `}`